# Registration and authorization on one page (Java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I need help. There is a page where the user can enter or register in the application. I do all this on one page and one view. If the registration works like an authorization, then the login refuses to work at all.

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String registration(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

    return "login";
}

@PostMapping("/login")
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") @Valid User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "login";
    }
    if (!userForm.getPassword().equals(userForm.getPasswordConfirm())){
        model.addAttribute("passwordError", "Пароли не совпадают");
        return "login";
    }
    if (!userService.saveUser(userForm)){
        model.addAttribute("usernameError", "Пользователь с таким именем уже существует");
        return "login";
    }

    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

**Thymeleaf:**

```
<div class="form-structor">
<div class="signup">
    <h2 class="form-title" id="signup"><span>или</span>Войдите</h2>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" >
    <div class="form-holder" >

        <input type="text" class="input" name="username" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="password" class="input" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

    </div>
    <button class="submit-btn">Войти</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="login slide-up">
    <div class="center">
        <h2 class="form-title" id="login"><span>или</span>Зарегистрируйтесь</h2>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" modelAttribute="userForm">
        <div class="form-holder">
            <input type="text" class="input" name="username" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="password" class="input" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="password" class="input" name="passwordConfirm" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <button class="submit-btn">Зарегистрироваться</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. Also note that "refuses to work at all" is very little information. In what way doesn't it work? What analysis did you do already? Did you step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: On a quick glance, how is this meant to work when I just try to log in? `!userForm.getPassword().equals(userForm.getPasswordConfirm())` - I'd not enter a password confirmation at all.

Comment: It does not work in the sense that the input is not processed in any way, the data from the login form is not sent anywhere, but registration works as authorization. I need registration to be registration and login to be login. I think that the problem is in the mapping, but there are no thoughts on how to solve the problem or split the views.

Comment: there is not enough information here for people to help you, I am guessing you are not even showing all of your controller methods but the reason behavior like you have described occurs is that post request just returns a view without redirect to get. Make sure to use redirects at all Post request controllers.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know Thymeleaf that well but your "login" form doesn't have a `modelAttribute` so that might be the problem. As for splitting the two: why don't you provide another controller mapped to let's say "/registration"? You'd not have to split the UI although that might make sense as well. What happens upon successful registration depends on your requirements. Options could be: a) treat the user as having successfully logged in, i.e. do the same as a normal login would do b) redirect the user to the login page (maybe add a message) c) validate registration first, e.g. by sending an email